# Supervisord: Restarting a group results in BAD_NAME

Tags: supervisord

I am running supervisord 3.0. My `supervisord.conf` file looks like this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
pidfile=/var/run/supervisor/supervisord.pid
minfds=1024
minprocs=200

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor/supervisor.sock

[program:p2]
command=...

[program:p1]
command=...

[group:myprograms]
programs=p1,p2
```

Using `supervisordctl` I can restart both programs individually.

```
$ supervisorctl restart p1
$ supervisorctl restart p2
```

However, attempting to restart the group results in an error.

```
$ supervisorctl restart myprograms:
error: <class 'xmlrpclib.Fault'>, <Fault 10: 'BAD_NAME: myprograms'>: file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py line: 799
```

How can I restart the group?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this was caused by a typo in my config file.